# Bit bucket clone in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, bitbucket-server, ibm-integration-bus

Trying to clone the branch from bit bucket using eclipse. Below i have wrote the steps which i have performed and the error i faced.

1) Installed TortoiseHG 4.0 32 bit from the [link](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/download/index.html)

2) Added & Updated the Mercurial software in the eclipse by followed steps in this [URL](https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main/wiki/Installation_and_Configuration.wiki#!installation-and-configuration)

3) I try to clone bit bucket repository in eclipse workspace as specified in the [link](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MercurialEclipse)
In this link, i have to mention bit bucket repository URL from where i have to clone. Hence I logged in bit bucket web url and navigated to the repository and clicked 3 dots. Then clicked clone under Actions. I got the URL. I have copied this URL and used it for Wizard in eclipse. Then clicked next. It throws me an error saying "**HTTP Error 501: Not Implemented**"

Error screeshot is.

[image: Error screenshot from eclipse]

My machine configuration :
Windows 7 32 bit.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: No. I could not make it work.